# set option to <select> using jquery with values acquired from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `<select>` tag with no `<option>` and I want to append values that has been queried with ajax. I used this method because my `<select>` tag is inside a **bootstrap modal**. How am I going to do it? I have here this code:

```
$('#update_job').on('show.bs.modal', function (event)  {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
        var id = $('.jobs').val();
        var modal=$(this);
        $('.modal-body #id').val(id)
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('Job_Order_Stage/getAllStatus')?>",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(result){
                var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 



            }
            $.each(result, function(i, item) {
            console.log("inserting", item);
            $('#status').append('<option value=>'.)

            });
        }); 
    });
```

In that `$('#status').append('<option value=>'.)`, I don't know how to set the value since it is surrounded by a single qoutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat the string

```
 $('#status').append('<option value="' + item + '">');
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
$('#status').append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value",item)
            .text(item));
```

or better(if you want) within your for-loop as :

```
$('#status').append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value",i)
            .text(item));
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you're allowed to double-quote single-quotes and vice-versa.

`console.log('hello "world"')` will output `hello "world"` and `console.log("hello 'world'")` will output `hello 'world'`.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done like:

```
$('#status').append("<option value='"+item+"'>"+item+'</option>');
```